# Output inline editing markup only on staging Web site, by DD4T Java version2

Tags: experience-manager, dd4t, siteedit

I have implemented a Web site by using DD4T Java version 2. I'll enable inline editing on the Web site.
Our requirements are following.

- Enable inline editing for all fields
- Only output inline editing markup on staging Web site, and not live Web site.

To enable inline editing, I'll add org.dd4t.springmvc.siteedit.SiteEditService class's methods to JSP.
It looks like following code(I omit some Java code to shorten it).

```
<h1>
<%= generateSiteEditFieldMarking() %>${heading}
</h1>
```

generateSiteEditFieldMarking method output "Start Component Field" comment and enbles inline editing.
Also the method output the comment only if site edit is enabled on siteeditsettings.xml, that means it doesn't output any markup on live Web site.

But if two fields value are included in one tag, following code doesn't enable inline editing on "message" field.

```
<h1>
<%=generateSiteEditFieldMarking() %>${heading}
<%=generateSiteEditFieldMarking() %>${message}
</h1>
```

In this case, I have to add a html tag(span) which includes each field, like following code.
I'm afraid those "span" tags will be output even on live Web site.

```
<h1>
<span><%=generateSiteEditFieldMarking() %>${heading}</span>
<span><%=generateSiteEditFieldMarking() %>${message}</span>
</h1>
```

How is it possible not to output any inline editing mark up on live Web site?

Comment: Which DD4T Maven version are you using ?

Comment: For dd4t version 2.0.1-beta and lower, you can check the siteeditsettings.xml file and set "enabled" to false. For 2.0.2, I'd recommend to have a look at the xpm.tld file

Comment: @Raimond I think the question is about not outputting the span tags which are only necessary for inline editing.